# foundation for emails can't create new project with npm error

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation and trying to start foundation for emails sass version. I installed foundation-cli by npm globally with this version:

> Foundation CLI version 2.2.5

Then I cd to an empty folder and try start a tester project by the following command

> foundation new --framework emails

The project setup failed:

> Downloading the project template... Done downloading!
>
> Installing dependencies...
>
> npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 4.0: fatal: ambiguous argument '4.0':
>   unknown revision or path not in the working tree. npm ERR! git
>   rev-list -n1 4.0: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like
>   this: npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 4.0: 'git  [...] --
>   [...]' npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 4.0:
>
> There were some problems during the installation.
>
> ✓ New project folder created.  ✗ Node modules not installed. Try
>   running npm install manually.  ✓ Bower components installed.

so I cd to the newly created project folder and npm install. It still failed.

> npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git checkout 4.0 npm
>   ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git. npm

Can anyone give me a hint how to resolve it??

Comment: Can you tell me what operating system you were using when you encountered this error? I'm experiencing the same issue, on Windows 10, and struggling to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there was once an 4.0 tag for Gulp but it was deleted. Just run `npm i gulp@next --save-dev` or `npm i gulp@4.0.0 --save-dev`.

It was fixed in https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/commit/a4472d7fc2409b43bbdc4df4dead7eb5e8e0e691 (see the change in package.json).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

First install gulp manually following these steps
https://gulpjs.org/getting-started.html.

Then if you get an error saying VCBuildtools arent't installed. Install them via

```
choco install vcbuildtools
```

After that it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I found it's the gulp problem as well. install it separately and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the manual install from here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails-template#manual-setup

Use Yarn instead of npm

Worked for me on a few different machines.

Comment: I see the instructions for a manual install.  But how exactly would I use Yarn instead of npm?  Can you walk me through those steps?  I've never used Yarn.